# Accessing window.open popup from excel online task pane

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

I am currently debugging some code that was done by past developers. 
We are using the below code to open a new window to authenticate the user (oAuth2 Flow).

> var oAuth2Window = window.open(_embeddedStartUrl, "Authentication",
>   "location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,height=600,width=450");

After the user logs in successfully, it's trying to access some properties on oAuth2Window but I am getting:

> “Access is denied”.

The host names are on different servers.

This is currently happening in Excel Online within a Task Pane.

This was tested some time ago and was working and went to production.

The past week I have seen this issue happening on local and production/live environments.

How could this worked previously? Knowing that you could not access the pop up window from an iframe

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this using this method from your different client applications.  Instead you need to route you OAuth workflow through the dialog API window.

See this link here [Using the Dialog APIs in an authentication flow](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) (near the bottom of the page).

Comment: Thanks Stewart for responding.

Is there any way for me to remove the "_host_info" that is getting added to the end of the URL?
This is causing 500 API errors on the oAuth2 server. Which I don't control

Comment: I don't believe so.  Also are you sure that the extra query string parameters are causing the 500 errors?  That strikes me as unusual.  Normally unknown or unexpected url parameters are just ignored.

Comment: I use Oauth2 to authorize my app.  What i did is i open a page with dialog api that goes to one of my local application pages.  From there i click a button to invoke the flow, then when the redirect comes back i'm not authorized and i use the call back functions to send back the access token i need back to the taskpane.  At which point i close the dialog api window.

Comment: Yep I agree, its unusual, I tested other URL’s and it works. 
I am going to contact that Oauth team and find out why.
Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi @StewardBeck, would it be possible for you to list your steps and process with an example please?

Reason why I am asking is that I am having issues with passing the access token back to the parent from the child. 
I had a look at Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync. This does not work for me in excel online because the oauth server page does not allow to be loaded in a iframe.

Comment: You can turn off the display in iFrame property.  If you do that then you'll be prompted each time it tries to open a new pop up, but it will at least function.  This isn't especially clean or nice but it does work.  I control my OAuth endpoint so i added the header to allow iframe when it came from my app.

Comment: Yep, agreed with Stewart.  You need to use the `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` method, but keep the option `displayInIframe: false` (which should be the default in any case). This will pop out the dialog outside the iframe, letting auth for services like Microsoft Graph through.  More info at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync.md

Comment: Hi Guys, Thank you for your help. I had no luck with the office dialog, however I found a solution using SignalR. What are your thought around SignalR?