# Opening a new window from Excel task pane add-in

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I was previously able to open a new window from code running in the task pane using the javascript below.

`window.open('/login.op')`

After upgrading to 16.1 Excel for Mac, it just opens a new blank window. The url I am attempting to open is on the same domain as the SourceLocation in manifest.xml

The problem with most other options is that they don't support an authentication involving SSO and redirects to domains not listed in the manifest.xml

Is there another authentication flow I should be looking at?

I am using `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js` which says it is `Version: 16.0.9010.1000`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing window.open popup from excel online task pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861297/accessing-window-open-popup-from-excel-online-task-pane)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT- in my case the url I am opening is on the same domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.open` and `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` do not support http in the context of a task pane. Serving the task pane content over https and updating the SourceLocation in manifest.xml to use https resolved the problem with both of calls.

Answer (score -1):

Please use [dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) for modal dialog interfaces. Dialog API is designed to provide uniform UI experience across platforms and browsers. The `window.open` may not be consistent across hosts/platforms and hence not recommended.

Comment: I did start to go down this route - but on 16.1 Excel for Mac the following code opens the link as a new tab in chrome
`Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('http://localhost:3001/slm/login.op', { width:20, height:20 }, () => {});` - if this is the supported path forward then I will open a separate question regarding this issue. Also your answer does not make it clear whether `window.open` is supported or not.

Comment: Add `displayInIframe: true` to your `options`. The default is `false` which will open the dialog in a new window/tab. When `true` the dialog will be surfaced within an IFRAME overlayed on top of the existing window.

Comment: Thanks for the response @MarcLaFleur-MSFT, unfortunately it does the same thing. The new line is `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('http://localhost:3001/slm/login.op', { displayInIframe: true });`

Comment: reading further I don't believe the dialog API will satisfy my requirements. The page cannot be displayed in an iframe because there will be redirections if the user has SSO configured and those pages will not run inside an iframe due to security. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/use-the-oauth-authorization-framework-in-an-office-add-in

It appears `window.open` is the way to do this, is there another reason it may not be working for me?

Comment: The URL resource that is passed to the displayDialogAsync method must be in the same domain as the host page. You can also design the first page to immediately redirect to another site. You may be directly trying to navigate to target address which could cause issues. Have you tried using one of the samples listed in the article? I don't know if your scenario is any different from those listed in the samples.